# What could be the delay in executing Thread.Start() method?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I am using a X_Trader(TT api) to get the prices for some products, whenever a new product price comes, i am calling a method inside a thread to update/insert into database,

`new Thread(()=>{ /*call method to insert/update*/ }).Start();`

The price for a product come asynchronously from a callback method. What could be the delay in inserting into database? Is there any specific thing I am missing?

Comment: How big is the delay?

Comment: sometimes its 5 minutes and sometimes no delay(i.e its in milliseconds)

Comment: Clearly, starting a thread does not take 5min. Therefore, the bug is in code that is not shown here. The question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: I also realize that some of the threads are getting queued, but is there a alternative way to do some operation which is executed immediately?

Comment: You did not understand what I said. Threads do not take 5min to get going. **Your code** takes 5min to execute. The reason why is unknown since the code is missing.

Comment: what if the thread gets queued? does that happen? I am sorry I am new to threading, is there any other way to do a operation immediately but asynchronously?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75708/discussion-between-kedark-and-usr).

Comment: I'll make one more attempt. Try `new Thread(()=>{ Console.WriteLine(x); }).Start();`. You'll see that the "x" appears very quickly in all cases. The only case where it would not would be if like 1000s of threads were running. I can't imagine that being the case.

Comment: I understood what you meant when you said it first, now my question is if there is any other alternative way for the process I am doing over here?

Comment: Find the delay that's inside of your threads code and remove it. Right now you seem to ask "how can I make a thread run immediately" but I told you that it does run immediately and you acknowledged. Where is the misunderstanding here? Don't you agree that the delay is in *your* code? Where else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely think about another way of handling those product updates.

Imagining that you get a high frequency of updates you will spawn a lot of threads which takes a lot of [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626803/why-is-creating-a-new-thread-expensive) (memory, CPU usage, etc.).

Take a look into the Task Parallel Library ([TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)) which is using a Thread Pool for optimized usage of a many parallel threads.

You can also collect all the updates in a stack and update the database once every 5 minutes (or less). This would save spawning many threads and won't bother the database with many single update queries in a short range of time.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, my requirement is such that I should not have to stack up the data and insert, requirement is also such that there should be no delay in fact. TPL would work in case of updating all at once, but my case is different.

Comment: Ah OK I understand. When you debug your code, can you validate that the delay is happening when executing the database update?

Comment: its hard to find out by debugging the code, there would be like 10-15 callbacks every second, I am actually looking for a alternative way to do some operation immediately on a thread

Comment: Do you debug in a productive environment? You should try to implement some unit tests that are mocked up. So you are able to test your code with a single update of test data. That way it's much more easy and reliable to test your code.
At all I am with usr in your discussion. But I can't comment because I am missing the needed reputation points.